# Species identification: what kind of fungus is this?

Tags: species-identification, species

Found in a cave
Location: Israel

The white tentacles appear to be sticky. When they touch something, they stick to it and detach from the main body

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please [edit] your post to include the size of these structures, where they were located in the cave (e.g. on the walls near the entrance), and why you concluded they were fungi. ——— If possible clear, closeup photos of the structures from multiple angles would also be helpful. Thanks! 

Answer (score 4):

**I think these are parasitized insects.**

Fungi of various types can infect insects.  The end stage produces these fruiting bodies.  Here is an example I found on the excellent site WhatsThatBug.

[image: moth with fungi]

Here is another example.

[image: moth with fungus]

http://www.anura.it/the-parasites-parasite-everyone-has-a-bad-day/clasp04/

The second site notes

> Entomopathogenic fungus (Clavicipitaceae sp.) killed a troglophile
>   moth, Veins cave (Grotta delle Vene), Italy

I would guess something similar for what you found.

I must say your images are incredible.  The long fungal tendrils on the second image are the most amazing example of this I have ever seen.